# Assign evil-mode keys dependent on major-mode

Tags: evil

I would like to assign [`evil-mode`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Evil) normal-state key bindings dependent on what major mode I am currently working in.

E.g. I am using [`org-mode`](http://orgmode.org) and I want a set of keys and if I use AucTeX I want a different set of keys.
Potentially there are keys that behave differently under different major modes because I want to keep a certain naming logic.

I tried assigning keys using different minor-modes, however the last loaded minor-mode overwrites the previously assigned key bindings. Switching to a different window with a different major mode *does not* switch the key bindings back.

Comment: Could you please close the question if it worked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `evil-define-key`.

For example to bind "a" in normal-state to different commands in org-mode and emacs-lisp-mode, you would do:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal org-mode-map "a" 'bar) 
(evil-define-key 'normal emacs-lisp-mode-map "a" 'foo)
```

Now "a" in normal state is bound to command `bar` in `org-mode` and command `foo` in `emacs-lisp-mode`.

Comment: Super. Gonna try that.